# Configuration settings for programming flash memory

Tags: embedded, microprocessor, flash, flash-memories, system-on-chip

I need to specify a memory addresses settings in the configuration file for programming flash memory with Macraigor Flash programmer utility. The device is BCM3360 (MIPS32) chip and flash memory is [640P30T](http://images.mjdic.com/Attachments/product/201311/5278c0e3ef9ee.jpg). The full  marking on flash chip is 640P30T A9027310 Z9022040B, I think its Intel flash chip [28F640P30T](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Micron%20Technology%20Inc%20PDFs/P30%20StrataFlash%20Embedded%20Memory.pdf), but I'm not 100% sure though, it can be also [Micron NOR Flash](https://www.micron.com/advanced-search?q=640P30T&part=true). 
I've selected 28F640P30T on  'Flash' tab of OCD Flash programmer, but I don't know about specific memory addresses I need to specify. 
In the 'Configuration' > 'Program' tab:

```
Target RAM starts at: $0000
Starts at: 0x00000000
Width: 16 x 1
```

The flash configuration file includes settings:

```
[SETUP]
CpuVendor=BroadCom
CpuChip=MIPS32
CpuEndian=BIG
FlashVendor=Intel
FlashChip=28F640P30T
RamAddress=$0000
FlashAddress=0x00000000
FlashWidth=16
FlashChipsPerSector=1
LittleEndian=0
SimCount=0
MemoryCount=0
TLBCount=0
ScanChainCount=0
```

Can anyone tell me what is an actual memory map for BCM3360 and Intel 28F640P30T flash memory? I need to specify the base address of RAM, the base address of Flash Memory, the bus width of Flash device.

```
RamAddress=$0000
FlashAddress=0x00000000
FlashWidth=16
FlashChipsPerSector=1
```

Since this hardware have no serial interface which usually displays the full configuration details during booting process, I can't get that info. Can anyone advice about mentioned settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really depends on your hex file. If your hex file covers the entire address space and has no odd/even split, then you generally can use 0x00 as the start address.
If your hex file only covers part of the address space, you need to check your code, compiler or linker settings for the right offset.
You should also be 100% sure about the correct vendor. Some devices require different settings, even for similar part numbers.

Comment: Well, this for uploading flash content, what if we want to dump the memory contents? Memory map details is not known.

Comment: Then you copy the entire device.

Comment: Not sure about these two parameters, the bus width of Flash device (eg 8-bits, 16-bits) and FlashChipsPerSector:
`FlashWidth=16`,
`FlashChipsPerSector=1`

Comment: Read the datasheet and your design schematics. Flash width is the device's data bus width. Flash chip per sector is a design configuration.